# SharePoint KQL Search string with apostrophe!

Tags: 2016, kql

I would like to return the search results for the documents which has apostrophe by using KQL (Programatically ) in sharepoint 2016. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a backslash "\" before the apostrophe.

As an alternative, you can use [SPEncode.UrlEncode method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spencode.urlencode.aspx) to encode your url, so the method will build the correct URL for you.

Comment: Tried, not working... without doing encoding it is working fine.